# Binary Tree Inorder Traversal

Tags: python, algorithm

I wrote such a solution to [Binary Tree Inorder Traversal - LeetCode](https://leetcode.com/problems/binary-tree-inorder-traversal/)

```
# Definition for a binary tree node.
# class TreeNode:
#     def __init__(self, x):
#         self.val = x
#         self.left = None
#         self.right = None

class Solution:
    def inorderTraversal(self, root: "TreeNode") -> "List[int]":
        stack, res = [root], []

        while stack:
            cur = stack[-1]
            cur = cur.left

            if cur == None:
                cur = stack.pop()
                res.append(cur.val)
                cur = cur.right 
            else:
                stack.append(cur)
                cur = cur.left 
        return res
```

but did not work as expected

```
Finished
Runtime: 48 ms
Your input  [1,null,2,3]
Output  [1]
Expected  [1,3,2]
```

What's the problem with my solution?

Comment: one [solution](https://leetcode.com/problems/binary-tree-inorder-traversal/discuss/325991/Python-Iterative-Solution-but-modifying-the-tree) is here, if you compare it with your

Comment: Have you tried debugging? What were your findings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problems with your solution are:

- if you don't have a left, you print the node and returning from the sub-tree without going right
- if you have a left, you append it. that can cause an infinite loop (when you'll return from the left you'll append it again)

To fix your solution:

- if you don't have a left, print the node **and put the right on the stack**
- if you have a left, put the left on the stack **and remove the left pointer from the TreeNode** so you won't add it again upon returning.

Another approach, if you can't destroy the tree:

- go all the way left, putting all the nodes along the way on the stack
- when removing a node from the stack, print it, go right and then all the way left, putting all the nodes on the stack.

class Solution:

```
def inorderTraversal(self, root: "TreeNode") -> "List[int]":
    stack, res = [root], []
    cur = stack[-1]
    while cur.left != None:
        stack.append(cur.left)
        cur = cur.left 
    while stack:
        cur = stack.pop()
        res.append(cur.val)
        if cur.right != None:
            stack.append(cur.right)
            cur = cur.right
            while cur.left != None:
                stack.append(cur.left)
                cur = cur.left 
    return res
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution when you write code with tree is very oftent to use recursion in your case the code that you search for would be :

```py
def inorderTraversal(root):
    result = []
    if root.left != None:
        result.extend(inorderTraversal(root.left))
    result.append(root.val)
    if root.right != None:
        result.extend(inorderTraversal(root.right))
    return result
```

If it is unclear please ask me, i will add more precision